# Python: Adding every second entry of list (beginner)

Tags: python, list

first off, it's a total "noob" question - thanks for your short time in advance!

I want to have a list and add all numbers from a list with an even index together. i.e. [1,2,3,4]=4

```
def sum_even(array):
    sum_array=array[0]
    for i in array:
        if i %2==0:
            sum_array=sum_array+array[i]
    print (sum_array)

sum_even([1,2,3,4,5,6])
```

This gives me an error (IndexError: list index out of range); sum([1,2,3,4,5]) works though.

What little thing am I doing wrong?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: `for i in array:` iterates over the values in the array, not the indexes. You need `enumerate()`.

Answer (score 1):

Your line

```
for i in array
```

itterates over the values not the keys and array indexes start from 0 therefore when it reaches the value '4' and tries to dereference array[4] it is out of bounds. You should instead use

```
for i in range(len(array))
```

which will itterate from 0 to 1-length of the array. A cleaner solution would be to make use of a list comprehension or filter e.g.

```
sum([x for x in sum_array[::2])
```

Answer (score 1):

You are iterating over the elements of the array. So by calling `sum_even([4, 5, 6])` when `i=4` your code calls `array[4]` attemptint to access the 4th element of the list, which doesn't exit.

You should simply do `sum_array=sum_array+i`. Or, you could do

```
for i, element in enumerate(array):
    if element %2==0:
        sum_array=sum_array+array[i]
```

Answer (score 0):

A more "pythonic" way to do this is :

```
print(range(1,5) )
>>> [1,2,3,4]
print(range(1,5)[::2] )
>>> [1,3]
print(range(1,5)[1::2] )
>>> [2,4]

print( sum( range(1,5) ))
>>> 10
print( sum( range(1,5)[::2] ))
>>> 4
print( sum( range(1,5)[1::2] ))
>>> 6
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def sum_even(array):
    sum_array=array[0]
    for i in range(len(array)):
        if i %2==0:
            sum_array=sum_array+array[i]
    print (sum_array)

sum_even([1,2,3,4,5,6])
```

when wanting to iterate through indexes, 
you want to iterate through a list of positions within the list

ex:
**if sum_even([7,6,3,4,5,6])**

```
for i in array:

i=7
i=6
i=3
i=4
i=5
i=6
```

indexes 7 and 6 dont exist since the list isn't long enough.

```
for i in range(len(array)):

i=0
i=1
i=2
i=3
i=4
i=5


len(array) = 6
range(6) = [0,1,2,3,4,5]
```

or a cleaner version:

```
def sum_even(array):
    return sum([x for x in array[::2]])

print sum_even([1,2,3,4,5,6])
```

[::2] means slice from position 0 every second position

*[1::2] means slice from position 1 every second position*

Answer (score 0):

you are trying to access array[6] but the array consists up to array[5] starting from Zero index. That is why showing error.Modify your function as

```
  def sum_even(array):
     sum_array=0
       for i,val in enumerate(array):
         #print "i=%d:: val=%d" % (i,val)
         if i %2==0:
            sum_array=sum_array+array[i]
     print (sum_array)

  sum_even([1,2,3,4,5,6])
```

Uncoment the print statement,u'll understand more.